# Why don't I get an error if a column referenced in a negative filter doesn't exist, and how might I add the error message?

Tags: r, dplyr

Take the following two dataframes:

```
onedf<-data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c"),
                  Count=c(7,80,23))

anotherdf<-data.frame(Car_ID=c("b","c","d"),
                      Color=c("red","green","blue"))
```

In an effort to get a filtered version of `onedf` where IDs are only preserved if they don't appear in `anotherdf`, I mistakenly refer to `anotherdr$ID` in the code below:

```
filtereddf<-onedf%>%
  filter(!(ID %in% anotherdf$ID))
```

Why is there no warning or error message produced, given the fact that no column named `ID` exists in `anotherdf`?

The result of running the above is simply `filtereddf` actually being an unfiltered version of `onedf`.  I think, however, that the code should brick, and alert me that `anotherdf$ID` does not exist.  If this happened, I would know to check my column names within `anotherdf` and would end up being able to correctly edit my code to

```
filtereddf<-onedf%>%
  filter(!(ID %in% anotherdf$Car_ID))
```

ultimately resulting in the `filtereddf` being a single row,

[image]

In practice, this filter is one of many steps in a project, and so the fact that no filtering and no error message is delivered makes this challenging to diagnose as the culprit in the ultimate erroneous output.

Is there a way to achieve this filter in such a way that this misnamed column reference would spark an error, or perhaps a way to force `filter()` to validate the column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is giving the full row is because if the column doesn't exist, it returns `NULL`, and when we do a `filter` with `%in%` on `NULL`, it returns FALSE. Negating (`!`), changes the FALSE to TRUE and thus we get all rows

```
anotherdf$ID
#NULL
onedf %>% 
    filter(ID %in% NULL)
#[1] ID    Count
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

onedf %>%
    filter(!ID %in% NULL)
#  ID Count
#1  a     7
#2  b    80
#3  c    23
```

It can be easily understood, if we create a column with `mutate`

```
 onedf %>%
    mutate(flag1 = ID %in% anotherdf$ID, flag2 = !flag1) 
#   ID Count flag1 flag2
#1  a     7 FALSE  TRUE
#2  b    80 FALSE  TRUE
#3  c    23 FALSE  TRUE
```

---

We could force to `stop` if there are no columns with that column name `exist` in 'anotherdf'

```
onedf %>%
     filter({stopifnot(exists('ID', where = anotherdf)); ID %in% anotherdf$ID})
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
✖ exists("ID", where = anotherdf) is not TRUE
ℹ Input `..1` is `{ ... }`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: This does the trick! Here's a function for filtering "not in" that'll stop if the column is incorrectly named based on @akrun  : `filter_notin_safe<-function(.data,otherdf,columnInData,columnInOtherDf){
  
  columnInData<-rlang::ensym(columnInData)
  columnInOtherDf<-rlang::ensym(columnInOtherDf)
  
  .data%>%
    filter({stopifnot(exists(as.character(columnInOtherDf), where = otherdf)); !(!!columnInData %in% otherdf[,names(otherdf) %in% c(columnInOtherDf)])})
}`